# Adicionar um programa de terceiro a um instalador

Tags: delphi, inno-setup

Estou utilizando o `InnoSetup` para gerar um instalador de uma aplicação `Delphi`.

Porem essa mesma aplicação depende o programa `R`, gostaria de saber se é possível acoplar o instalador do `R` ao meu instalador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível.
Basicamente você pode adicionar o instalador 'R', como um recurso no seu próprio instalado, e tratar para que o seu processo aguarde a instalação do 'R'

Segue um exemplo, onde o dotnetfx35 é necessário:

`[Files]
Source: D:\dsv\projetos\geral\Instalador\nfe\dotnetfx35_sp1.exe; DestDir: {#MyAppDirIns}; Flags: ignoreversion`

`[Run]
Filename: {#MyAppDirIns}\dotnetfx35_sp1.exe;`

Comment: mas eu não posso acoplar o instalador do r, para o cara ser obrigado a instalar quando já estive instalando meu programa?

Comment: é isso que vai acontecer. Quando executar o seu instalador, se essa rotina vier primeiro, ele vai abrir o exe obrigando o usuario a instalar o R, apos isso, vai seguir na instalação do seu App.

Comment: Muito bom funcionou corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,

Apenas reforçando com outro exemplo, vou mostrar parte do script de instalação do ERP da minha empresa:

```
[Files]
Source: "..\..\..\SetupSystec\Systec\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs promptifolder; Languages:  brazilianportuguese; Permissions: system-full
Source: "..\..\..\SetupSystec\Componentes\*"; DestDir: "{app}\Componentes\"; Flags: ignoreversion createallsubdirs recursesubdirs

[Run]
Filename: {app}\Componentes\TDBGrid7.0.0285_patch.exe
Filename: {app}\Componentes\psqlodbc.msi; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated
```

Neste exemplo, a pasta "Componentes" recebe arquivos de terceiros. Colocando os programas na mesma, na tag [Run] é só indicar como vc quer que os os programas sejam executados. Para sua instalação continuar apenas depois do X programa instalado, colocar a flag **"Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated"**

Comment: parabéns pela atitude, vai ajudar os outros.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima Obrigado!